# Dimension of $M_{n \times n}$ over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, cayley-hamilton

Let $M_{n \times n}$ be the set of all $n$-square matrices and the characteristics polynomial of each $A\in M_{n \times n}$ is of the form $a_nt^n+a_{n-1}t^{n-1}+...+a_1t+a_0$. Then the dimension of $M_{n \times n}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is...

The answer provided is $(n-1)(n+2)/2$. I don't have any idea about how to approach it.

All I know, that in general, $\dim(M_{n \times n})=n^2$ and every square matrix satisfies its characteristic polynomial. Please help me out.

Comment: The characteristic polynomial of any $n\times n$ matrix has the form $a_nt^n+a_{n.-1}t^{n-1}+...+a_1+a_0$ (in fact, with $a_n=1$), so something seems off.

Comment: @Thorgott exactly. No specific property has been mentioned.

Comment: In that case I am very confused by the problem statement. Where did you take this from?

Comment: @Thorgott An MCQ book. Contains a fair amount of typographical errors.

Comment: I suspect this is one of them then. Though I have to admit that I have no clue what the statement was intended to be either.

Comment: Agree, in any case the factor of n+2 is intriguing. Maybe you can show us the passage of the book

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst no passage, no nothing. Just a stray problem.

Comment: Among ~300 other problems from linear algebra